# Pandas Dataframe Fast Join by Date

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join

I have two pandas dataframe, each using DatetimeIndex as index. I would like to join these two dataframe by their corresponding date while throwing away all hour/minute/second information.

All I can think of is to create a date column first using df.index.strftime or df.index.date. The former one creates a date column of string, and the latter solution creates a date column of datetime.date. However, these two operations are extremely slow for large dataframe more than a few million rows. Is there any faster ways for doing this by simply using the original index? Any other suggestion is also welcome.

Comment: the question isn't clear to me yet, could you post a short sample of what the two database indexes look like. if you have multiple timestamps per date in both data frames, how do you handle this many-many join?

Comment: See [`DatetimeIndex.normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.normalize.html)

Comment: @root yes this works well and fast, thanks